# Destroying and creating CKEDITOR in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, ckeditor, reactjs

I'm having trouble creating a new editor and deleting one once the state changes here is a example of what I'm trying to do:

**componentDidMount**

```
componentDidMount() {
ReportsActions.getMyReports();
ReportsStore.listen(this._onChange);
CKEDITOR.replace( 'ckedits', {
  allowedContent : true,      
  pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles : false,
  pasteFromWordRemoveStyles : false
  });
console.log(CKEDITOR.instances);
console.log("called");
    }
```

**I call ckeditor in this method in react to initialize it, and it works fine.**

**onChange function**

```
_change = () => {
  this.setState({
    isWaiting : "blah"
  });
  for (var instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    CKEDITOR.remove(CKEDITOR.instances[instance]);       
    CKEDITOR.instances.instance.destroy(); 
  }
//CKEDITOR.replaceAll();
  CKEDITOR.replace( 'ckedits', {
  allowedContent : true,      
  pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles : false,
  pasteFromWordRemoveStyles : false
  });
}
```

As for the onchange method, it is invoked on a click of a button, it changes the state but should atleast destroy and ckeditor instance. The error returned is that is cannot read clearCustomData of null, and if I write onchange like this it is:

```
_change = () => {
  this.setState({
    isWaiting : "blah"
  });
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['ckedits'];
if (editor) { editor.destroy(true); }
CKEDITOR.on('instanceDestroyed', function(evt){
CKEDITOR.replace('ckedits');
});
}
```

then my error becomes 'cannot read proper getselections of null. When the state does change it just becomes a regular text area instead of the ckedit instance overwriting that.

Any suggestions on how to overcome this? It might be because the page isn't reloading, if I hit refresh it'll show the editor. So it might not work as well with states in react js.

textarea:

```
<textarea className = "ckeditor" name = "ckedits" id = "ckedit" ref = "body" defaultValue = "Enter Body Here"></textarea>
```

Comment: Try putting your CKEDITOR stuff in a callback function to this.setState.  Don't forget that setState is not necessarily synchronous.

Comment: I'm confused on how this would work, wouldn't this also force another instance of creation of setstate was somehow called again.